# Navigator problem, does not go anywhere flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, navigator

I am creating a notification and when I click on it I need to go to some route.
I have a listener and when I click I use payload to go to some screen.
These functions are all in my main.dart and it is called in initState().

```
listenNotifications() =>
      NotificationService.onNotifications.stream.listen(onClickedNotification);

  onClickedNotification(String? payload) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => QuestsScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I know that it enter in onClickedNotification because if I can print something inside the function.
When I click I got an error that does not appear in console. The error is in errors_patch.dart, and says this "@patch
@pragma("vm:external-name", "Error_throwWithStackTrace")
external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);"
I don´t know what I am missing here

Comment: Is MaterialApp defined in build method of this State class? If yes, I can provide resolution.

Comment: Yes It is. Can you help me?

Comment: Try to add GlobalKey to navigation in material app and use that to push route.